# Ломается кодировка вывода PyCharm в режиме дебага

Tags: python, кодировка, pycharm, utf

Использую PyCharm. При обычном запуске проекта проблем не возникает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, запуская проект в режиме отладки ломается вся кириллица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решение этой проблемы - хороший повод подтянуть свой английский.

Answer (score 0):

Решение изменить кодировку на UTF-8:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]